# Jquery Mask with placeholder not working as expected

Tags: jquery, regex

I am trying to make a placeholder for a text box the user enters time into, in 15 minute increments. (e.g. 1h 30m is a valid increment, 2h 23m is not).

I can achieve this using a placeholder with a translation:

```
$('#withTranslation').mask(
        'Ah BCm', {
        translation: {
            'A': { pattern: /[0-9]/ },            
            'B': { pattern: /[1|3|4]/ },
            'C': { pattern: /[0|5]/ },            
        },
        placeholder: "_h __m"
    });
```

but this will still allow the values Xh 35m and Xh 40m which are invalid. Is there a better way I can acheive this?

Also, I want the placeholder to remain when the user enters / deletes text, like this: 
[image]

(see http://jsfiddle.net/bdgriffiths/SEXAj/5036/)

However, at the moment when the user backspaces, the "m" in the placeholder appears again in a funny place:

[image]

(see http://jsfiddle.net/bdgriffiths/f7uc8d7t/46/)

Comment: The mask is great but, would it not be more user friendly to just have a simple hours dropdown with 1-9 and a minutes dropdown with 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30. Using the keyboard to type this seems very strange to me. IMO masks are great for Phone Numbers and "on the fly" email validation. It seems like this is the wrong place for a mask to me.

Comment: I thought about a dropdown - the issue is that the user will be filling in lots of these textboxes at a time (it's a timesheet system). To do that with a mouse will likely be slower than with a keyboard.